# Pagenation in single agent page not working wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a single agent page in that page i am trying to list all the property by the agent in that property area i have kept an bootstrap pagination that was not working it was showing the page numbers but when you click that was not taking to page1 or page 2 etc. But it was redirecting to the same page. Here is my code.

```
get_header();
<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row bkg-white bkg-pd-top">
<div class="container">
<?php if (have_posts()) : 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> >
    <div class="col-md-9"><div class="row">
<div class="single-details">
<div class="single-sec-prop-title">Agent Details</div>
<div class="single-prop-detail">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="row"><div class="agent-single-image">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('small-img-featured', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
</div></div></div>
</div>
</div></div>    
</div></div>

<div class="single-details">
<div class="single-sec-prop-title">Description</div>
<div class="single-prop-detail">   
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="row">
<div class="single-sec-prop-title agent-single-title">Listed Properties</div>
<?php
endwhile; 
endif;

if (get_query_var('paged')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif (get_query_var('page')) { 
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('forsale', 'forrent'),
'numberposts' => -1,
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'paged' => $paged,  //very important
'meta_key' => 'select-agent',
'meta_value' => get_the_id(),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/property', 'agent' );  
endwhile;  ?>
<?php 
if ($custom_query->max_num_pages > 1) :
$orig_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = $custom_query;
?><nav class="prev-next-posts">
<?php
if (function_exists('wp_bootstrap_pagination')){
wp_bootstrap_pagination();
}
?>
</nav>
<?php endif;
 wp_reset_postdata();
else:
 get_template_part( 'template-parts/no', 'post' ); 
endif;  //ends loop

?>

<?php 
get_footer();
```

Here is the link for bootstrap pagenation code [Bootstrap pagenatio](https://github.com/talentedaamer/Bootstrap-wordpress-pagination/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_pagination.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a answer for your question. If you need to add an pagenation to your single page for example your single agent page you need to set a template redirect function in wordpress for that you need to add the following code to your active themes function.php In this code please change the agent to your custom post type if your custom post is not agent.

```
 add_filter('redirect_canonical','redirect_single_page');

    function redirect_single_page($redirect_url) {
    if (is_singular('agent')) $redirect_url = false; // change 'agent' to your custom post type, obviously
    return $redirect_url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with wordpress.

```
<?php 
get_header(); ?>
<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row bkg-white bkg-pd-top">
<div class="container">
<?php if (have_posts()) : 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> >
    <div class="col-md-9"><div class="row">
<div class="single-details">
<div class="single-sec-prop-title">Agent Details</div>
<div class="single-prop-detail">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="row"><div class="agent-single-image">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('small-img-featured', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
</div></div></div>
</div>
</div></div>    
</div></div>

<div class="single-details">
<div class="single-sec-prop-title">Description</div>
<div class="single-prop-detail">   
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="row">
<div class="single-sec-prop-title agent-single-title">Listed Properties</div>
<?php
endwhile; 
endif;

if (get_query_var('paged')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif (get_query_var('page')) { 
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('forsale', 'forrent'),
'numberposts' => -1,
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'paged' => $paged,  //very important
'meta_key' => 'select-agent',
'meta_value' => get_the_id(),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/property', 'agent' );  
endwhile;  

customPagination($paged,$custom_query);


endif;
 wp_reset_postdata();
else:
 get_template_part( 'template-parts/no', 'post' ); 
endif;  //ends loop

?>

<?php 
get_footer();

?>


<?php 
function customPagination($paged,$probj){

            $data = '';
            $data .='<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">';
                $pager = 999999999; 
                $pargs = array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $pager, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $pager ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
                    'total' => $probj->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_next'=> false,
                    'type'=> 'array'
                );      
                $links = paginate_links( $pargs );              

                if ( $links ) :

                    $data .= '<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';

                    // get_previous_posts_link will return a string or void if no link is set.
                    if ( $prev_posts_link = get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Previous Page' ) ) ) :
                        $data .= '<li class="prev-list-item">';
                        $data .= $prev_posts_link;
                        $data .= '</li>';
                    endif;

                    $data .= '<li class="page-item">';
                    $data .= join( '</li><li class="page-item">', $links );
                    $data .= '</li>';

                    // get_next_posts_link will return a string or void if no link is set.
                    if ( $next_posts_link = get_next_posts_link( __( 'Next Page' ) ) ) :
                        $data .= '<li class="next-list-item">';
                        $data .= $next_posts_link;
                        $data .= '</li>';
                    endif;
                    $data .= '</ul>';
                endif;



            $data .='</nav>';
            echo $data;
        }


?>
```

I have added one function at your code please refere this.

Comment: Do you know why the bootstrap pagination was not working

Comment: kaushal bhatt i have tried your code same issue is going on in your code too.