# Wordpress : Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function posts_custom_columns(), 1 passed in

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress getting following error

> (Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function posts_custom_columns(), 1 passed in )

when enabling the featured image in admin list. Here is the code which i have added in functions.php

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_columns');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns');
    function posts_columns($defaults){
    $defaults['wdm_post_thumbs'] = __('Featured Image'); //name of the column
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_columns($column_name, $id){
        if($column_name === 'wdm_post_thumbs'){
        echo the_post_thumbnail(array(75,75)); //size of the thumbnail 
    }
}
```

While removing this no error. I need to know what was wrong with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`manage_posts_custom_column()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) you'll see that it takes 2 arguments. *(Note, the second one is typically denoted as `$post_id`)*.

Now, if you look at the documentation for [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) you'll see it takes 4 arguments, the third being `priority`, and the fourth being the number of arguments sent to the function. Since you're passing more than the default of `1`, you need to update your code to:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns', 10, 2 );
```

So here's what I'd do to improve it as written:

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'posts_columns' );
function posts_columns( $defaults ){
    $defaults['wdm_post_thumbs'] = __('Featured Image'); //name of the column
    return $defaults;
}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns', 10, 2 );
function posts_custom_columns( $column_name, $post_id ){
    if( $column_name === 'wdm_post_thumbs' ){
        echo the_post_thumbnail( array(75,75) ); //size of the thumbnail 
    }
}
```

Note, that if you're not specifically using the `$post_id` parameter, you can omit it from your function declaration instead:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns' );
function posts_custom_columns( $column_name ){
    if( $column_name === 'wdm_post_thumbs' ){
        echo the_post_thumbnail( array(75,75) ); //size of the thumbnail 
    }
}
```

A last note, is that you may want to consider renaming your functions, as `posts_custom_columns` is ripe for a naming collision without being namespaced or in a class.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the nice explanation.

Comment: Can you able to guide me whats wrong with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082126/pagenation-in-single-agent-page-not-working-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns');
```

to

```
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns', 10, 2);
```